Childress CFT, Exercise 4.1
In her chapter on Idelic theory, Childress defines a mapping
$$\left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert : F \to [0, \infty)$$
that satisfies $\left\Vert 0 \right\Vert = 0$, restricts to a homomorphism of multiplicative groups $F^\times \to \mathbb{R}^\times_{+}$, and has the property that
$$\left \Vert 1 + x \right \Vert \leq c \hspace{.5cm} \text{whenever} \left\Vert x \right\Vert \leq 1$$
for a fixed constant $c$ with $c \geq 1$.
She claims in exercise 4.1 that for any such mapping there exists a positive real number $\lambda$ such that $\left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert^\lambda$ satisfies the triangle inequality. When $c = 1$ it's easy to see that such a $\lambda$ exists. Supposing without loss of generality that $\left \Vert y \right \Vert \geq \left\Vert x \right \Vert$, we have $\left\Vert 1 + \frac{x}{y} \right \Vert \leq 1$ and multiplying through by $\left\Vert y \right\Vert$ we obtain the strong triangle inequality. So $\lambda = 1$ works in this case.
The issue I'm running into is when $c > 1$. Reducing to the case of considering $x$ with $\left\Vert x \right \Vert \leq 1$, we need to show that there exists a lambda with $\left \Vert 1 + x \right\Vert^\lambda \leq 1 + \left\Vert x \right\Vert^\lambda$. The challenge here is that as $\left\Vert x \right\Vert \to 0$, it's not immediately clear what happens to $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert$. So far, I've been able to rule out the absolute worst-case scenario: where $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert = c$ regardless of how small $\left\Vert x \right\Vert$ is (which is good, because otherwise there'd be no $\lambda$ that works!). For example, if $x$ is such that $\left\Vert x \right \Vert < \min\{\frac{1}{c^2}, \left\Vert 2 \right\Vert \}$, then $\left\Vert 2x + x^2 \right \Vert \leq 1$. It follows that $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert^2 \leq c$, hence that $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert = c - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. One can then solve for the minimum possible value of $\epsilon$ and obtain $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert \leq \sqrt{c}$
From this work, it seems plausible to me that as $\left\Vert x \right\Vert \to 0$ the upper bound on $\left\Vert 1 + x \right\Vert$ decreases in a such a way that one can find a $\lambda$ for which $\left \Vert 1 + x \right\Vert^\lambda \leq 1 + \left\Vert x \right\Vert^\lambda$. However, I'm finding it hard to generalize the work above. Any suggestions for pushing this argument further, or for a different approach entirely, are much appreciated.

This is not my original proof, but taken from Cassel's and Fröhlich's Algebraic Number Theory (p.43). First note that by replacing $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ by some power we may assume $C=2$. If $0\ne\lVert x\rVert \geq\lVert y\rVert$, then $\lVert x+y\rVert=\lVert x\rVert \lVert1+yx^{-1}\rVert\leq2\lVert x\rVert$, so $\lVert x+y\rVert \leq2\max\{\lVert x\rVert, \lVert y\rVert\}$ for all $x,y\in F$. From this one quickly deduces that $\lVert x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n\rVert\leq 2n\max\{\lVert x_1\rVert,\dots, \lVert x_n\rVert\}$ for all $x_1,\dots,x_n\in F$. This implies $\lVert n\rVert\leq 2n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Then\begin{align*}
\lVert x+y\rVert^n&=\lVert (x+y)^n\rVert=\lVert \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^ky^{n-k}\rVert\\
&\leq 2(n+1)\max_{k=0,\dots, n}\lVert\binom nk x^ky^{n-k}\rVert\\
&\leq2(n+1)\max_{k=0,\dots, n}2\binom nk \lVert x\rVert^k\lVert y\rVert^{n-k}\\
&\leq 4(n+1)(\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert)^n.
\end{align*}
Now take $n$th roots and let $n\to\infty$.

This is very nice, thanks @leoli1!
